# Elastic Search with Remote Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm trying to configure ElasticSearch on my workstation to work with a large collection on a remote mongo database. I installed the river but I can't make it work. I have is this configuration elements :

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{ 
"type": "mongodb", 
"mongodb": { 
"host":"10.42.210.214",
"port":"27017",
"login":"admin",
"password":"something",
    "db": "somedb", 
    "collection": "somecollection"
}, 
"index": {
    "name": "mongoindex", 
    "type": "somecollection" 
}
}'
```

When I search by:

```
http://localhost:9200/somecollection/_search?query=matchAll&pretty=true
```

... it says:

```
{ "error" : "IndexMissingException[[somecollection] missing]", "status" : 404 }
```

How can I make it index stuffs / debug the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the answer from Elasticsearch is `no collection`?

I'm curious to see the result sent by ES.

BTW, did you enable mongodb [replica set](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Set+Tutorial)?

Comment: it says : {
  "error" : "IndexMissingException[[somecollection] missing]",
  "status" : 404
}

Comment: Which is a bit different than "no collection"! :-) So did you enable replica set on Mongo? Anything in elasticsearch logs?

Comment: Replica was not set... sorry. And my configuration was incorrect : there is a "server" element with "host" and "port" in it and another named "credentials" where there is "user" (not login) and "password". Since replica was part of the problem, I consider your anwser part of the accepted anwser. Thks.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `http://localhost:9200/mongoindex/_search?query=matchAll&pretty=true` to do the search. Look at the **mongoindex**.